# no matches found when accessing multiple files for hadoop job on EMR

Tags: python, hadoop, amazon-s3, mrjob

I'm trying to run a hadoop job on AWS EMR that I execute locally using python on files in s3.  I cannot seem to be able to access multiple files using `*`.  I want to be able to access all files from the folder 01 on.  This code works on all files in this folder:

```
    python mapper_reducer.py -r emr s3://firehose/2017/01/30/20/ --output-dir=s3://job-results
```

This code gets the error `no matches found: s3://firehose/2017/01/*/*/`

```
    python mapper_reducer.py -r emr s3://firehose/2017/01/*/*/ --output-dir=s3://job-results
```

Is this an issue with mrjob?  I tried adding a `--recursive` flag with no result